# how to delete null elements from a object list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have such a list:

```
[{id: null, secilenMiktar: null, depoId: null}, {id: 3737, secilenMiktar: 1.0, depoId: 13}, {id: null, secilenMiktar: null, depoId: null}, {id: null, secilenMiktar: null, depoId: null}]
```

I want to delete all elements with null id from this list

like this: `[{id: 3737, secilenMiktar: 1.0, depoId: 13}]`

Thank you!

edit: (Regarding pskink's answer)
[image]

Comment: `yourList.removeWhere((e) => e.id == null && ...)`

Comment: i don't have access to id value from e

Comment: I added a picture about it

Comment: sorry: `e['id']` and not `e.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's say you have this list here.

```
 final List<Map<String, dynamic>> myList = [
    {"id": null, "secilenMiktar": null, "depoId": null},
    {"id": 3737, "secilenMiktar": 1.0, "depoId": 13},
    {"id": null, "secilenMiktar": null, "depoId": null},
    {"id": null, "secilenMiktar": null, "depoId": null},
  ];
```

To remove elements where the `id` is null, you can use the [removeWhere](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html) and check if the the current `Map` with the key `id` is null.

```
 myList.removeWhere((e) => e["id"] == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
 (requestObj["detayIds"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
          .removeWhere((element) => element.values.first== null);
```